# Only one network is really unstable on only one computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I just bought a new ASUS F551CA. When using it, be it Fedora or Windows, my home network is really unstable. While it works perfectly on all other devices, I barely get one bar on my homenetwork. I have tried to connect it to my mobile network, where it works perfectly. The network driver is Quallcom Atheros, recently updated.

Can this be a problem with the firmware of the router, seeing as the router is pretty old while the computer is brand new?

It would seem that the main problem is that I basically get a very weak signal.

Answer (score 1):

- **Update you network driver**
- **Try this :**

  1. Click start
  2. RUN
  3. Type `cmd` and press enter
  4. Type `netsh winsock reset` and press enter

When this is done, restart the computer. Many antivirus programs can corrupt the winsock catalogs which give the exact problem that you are having. Try this and let me know how this goes.

- **Disable the power saving feature of the wireless adapter :**

[image]

Be sure that the below item in **not** checked :

[image]

- **Disconnect some devices of your computer (external hard, ...)**
- **maybe disabling antivirus could help you too! :)**

Thank you.

Comment: The first option did not solve my problem. The second option is unavailable to me, as suggested my the picture I included. Thanks again, though.

Comment: OK :( I'll wait for other answers :)

Comment: Oh, I just tried your second option, didn't work. Same for third and fourth.

Comment: Ooof :( Maybe other peoples can help us :)